Linear Actuator with remote controller and current limiting
i have a Door that swing up and down to open and close using two linear actuators on both sides. i want to control it using a rf remote and buttons from panel. i didnt want to use limit switchs for limiting both end becuse of wiring so i want to use current sensor to cut off power.
so this is the circuit i came up with the parts i have
for

J4 is 24v input and i used a  diod for reverse polarity protection.
J1 is 220v

for current switch circuit i used ACS712_05 and UA741 OpAmp for each of motors. to set current limit i used 100K Potentiometer. maybe i can use shunt resistors but i had ACS712 modules and i think its good to have Ac And Dc voltages isolated this way.

for the remote control i used a RX480R receiver module. i just need 2 channel. for driving relays ULN2003 is easier. two buttons on panel for Emergency.
Relays K1 and K2 for disturbing power and Relays K3 and K4 for Open And Close
Q1 and Q2 Making AND Gate so if any of motors Current sensor is set both the motors Stop.
What do you think is it working properly :) any suggestion?

Have you tried simulating your circuit?

no, im begginer and i just used proteuse in the paste  for simulation but i dont have it anymore

Are you able to get newer/better opamps?  741 are very poor in performance, and far from ideal.  They'll affect your adjustment range and temperature drift big time compared to modern parts. Also, LTSpice is a free and very good simulation tool.

If you add another resistor in series with VR1 and VR2, you can improve the adjustability of the current set point.

how about  LM358 is it good? or if you recommend any? i just downloaded LTSpice but i hope i can work with it :) how about the rest of circuit?

There are many issues:

This will oscillate: Once the current limiter turns the motor off, the limiting condition is removed and this will enable the motor again.
You need vertically swapped PNPs for Q1 and Q2 to get 24 V at the relay coils.
If I remember correctly, pin 1 and 5 of 741 should not be connected to GND.
If you feed the 741 with just 5 V, the OpAmp output voltage is by far not sufficient to control Q1 and Q2.
The motor startup current will always trigger the current limit and immediately stop the motor.
Since these are AC motors, the output of the current sensors will be pulsed with the grid frequency. This is no useful signal to control the relays.
You need clamping diodes across K1 and K2 because the internal diodes of the ULN are decoupled by the transistors.
C5 with 22 nF is not sufficient for stable operation of the 7805.


thanks for your answer. there are so many problems :).    1. if i use a micro i can monitor current sensors and turn off Relays at the setpoint.  2.how about bc557 but if i @Jens use micro i dont need it  3. i used this link as refrence so its wrong?  5. if i use a micro i can set a time delay in the start of motor to check sensors value  how about this changes or i need another approach

The circuit behind the link is not wrong, but does not fit into the circuit. An AC load current produces an AC signal (with offset) at the sensor output. You can feed an ADC with that and solve all the issues in software.
